# Arraylist inside instance is not private

Tags: java, class, arraylist

When I create an instance I create an ArrayList inside that instance and I get a pointer of that exact instance but when I add items to that ArrayList it kinda doesn't add it to it but adds to kinda like a "public" list...
When matchmaking is found it grabs SocketChannel id of 2 players in matchmaking and adds them to a Room which is created (at least it should), but it doesn't...

This is how I create an ArrayList in room class:

```
private static ArrayList<SocketChannel> room_players = new ArrayList<SocketChannel>();
```

This is the code when 2 players are found in matchmaking:

```
room Room = new room(); //
System.out.println("Making a new room");
ArrayList<SocketChannel> player_list = Room.getPlayerList();
SocketChannel s1 = matchmakingPlayers.get(i);
SocketChannel s2 = matchmakingPlayers.get(i-1);
_main.rooms.add(Room);
player_list.add(s1);
player_list.add(s2);
```

This is the output when I have 2 clients connected:

```
2 Players were found
Making a new room
Number of players in room: 2
```

But the output when I have 2 players already in the game and I want to matchmake new 2 is:

```
2 Players were found
Making a new room
Number of players in room: 4
```

Thank you very much for any kind of help or advice!

Comment: `private` in Java means (roughly speaking) "private to a class and its nested classes".  It doesn't mean "private to a single instance".   So even if you remove the `static`, a method call in another instance can still see and modify a `private` variabe in some circumstance.

Comment: `room Room = new room();`??? You got your casing flipped. Java naming convention is for class names to start with uppercase letter, and for variable names to start with lowercase letter, so it should be `Room room = new Room();`

Comment: Also I recommend that you program to the interface and use `List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();` instead of `ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `room_players` is a static member, it's shared by all instances of the class. Removing the `static` modifier would give each `Room` instance it's own separate instance of that variable.

```
private final List<SocketChannel> room_players = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But how can I access it now from other classes?

Comment: Use a getter method.

Comment: @BMatjasic you can make it a singleton class then create a getter for that property.

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I access it now from other classes?

There are different ways:
You can change the member from private to public...

```
public final List<SocketChannel> room_players = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can create a public method for getting the value...

```
public List<SocketChannel> getRoom_players() {
    return room_players;
}
```

You can also make the class a Singleton. If you want to have only one instance of the class to be shared and accessible from anywhere in the application. Maybe it makes no sense in your case. Info: https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples

Comment: Hmm but I'm having an issue then when I try to fetch an actual list: ArrayList p_list = getPlayerList(); that I need to change room_players to static...

Comment: Maybe you are trying to access room_players from a static context, can you post more code so we can understand an overall view?